# Installing Riari/Laravel forum with composer - error - class not found

Tags: laravel, composer-php, forum

I am trying to install Riari forum for Laravel and I follow strictly the steps from http://teamteatime.net/docs/laravel-forum/3.x/installation.md

When I type **php artisan vendor:publish** in the console, it gives me this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]
>     Class 'Riari\Forum\ForumServiceProvider' not found

How can I fix it?

Comment: Have you updated your app.php ?

Comment: Yes, I added **'Riari\Forum\ForumServiceProvider',**  in the providers array.

Comment: Also installed the frontend ? and then done your migration ?

Comment: As far as I see the front-end is optional ("recommended") and I didn't do my migration, because it is the next step after I receive my files from vendor:publish, which I can't do.

Comment: Ahm, just for checking, can u install front-end and test that ?

Comment: I installed it, but there is no change.. still class not found.

Comment: I just ran through the process and it all seems to be working fine.  Check your console and make sure composer actually installed it successfully.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this (Riari\Forum\ForumServiceProvider) in Config/app.php inside service provider in the same format where already some providers are added